# Twig - Sandbox security policy won't work

Tags: php, symfony, twig, sandbox, twig-extension

I have been trying to get this to work for a while now and can't find much docs on it. Or any use cases where the sandbox policy has been used outside of the Symfony framework.

I'm using Twig as a stand-alone package, so can't use any Symfony pseudo-code.

I have strict mode enabled so the sandbox affects all templates. Most templates render fine except this one which makes a call to a class. However I don't know how to allow it through.

Class:

```
class GetThings {

    public function doStuff() {
        return array(
            'id'   => '...',
            'data' => '...'
        );
    }

}

...
```

Twig:

```
$allowedTags = ['if', 'else', 'elseif', 'endif', 'for', 'endfor'];
$allowedFilters = ['upper', 'escape'];
$allowedMethods = [
    'GetThings' => array('doStuff') // Possibly this may be wrong?
];
$allowedProperties = [
    'GetThings' => array('id', 'data') // Or this is wrong? But not sure the correct way.
];
$allowedFunctions = ['range'];

$policy = new Twig_Sandbox_SecurityPolicy($allowedTags, $allowedFilters, $allowedMethods, $allowedProperties, $allowedFunctions);
$sandbox = new Twig_Extension_Sandbox($policy, true);

...
```

Template:

```
{% for i in info %}
    {{ i.id }}       <- Code that raises securityPolicy exception.
    {{ i.data }}     <- Code that raises securityPolicy exception.
{% endfor %}
```

I believe it may be related to the allowed methods or properties, but I wasn't able to find any working examples of these in use. I've tried the full namespaces too, nothing.

**EDIT**:
So I looked into this error a bit deeper and found the exception stack-trace, for some reason it thinks my class is StdClass rather than GetThings? Not sure why. Any ideas?

`Twig_Sandbox_SecurityNotAllowedPropertyError: Calling "id" property on a "stdClass" object is not allowed.`

To instantiate the class I simply do the following:

```
public function index() {
    $data = new GetThings();
    // echo get_class($data); // returns GetThings as expected...

    return $twig->render('index.twig', [
        'info' => $data->doStuff()
    ]);
}
```

If I do `'StdClass' => array('id', 'data')` for the allowed properties, the page works fine. But I feel this is not working as intended, as StdClass could be anything? And GetThings should work, no?

**EDIT**:

I think I figured it out. So my allowed properties allows `'GetThings' => [id, data]` which is fine. `doStuff()` returns a `\PDO` array of objects, using the `\PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_OBJ` option which causes PDO to convert all returned values into `StdClass` objects.

Is there any way around this? I want to keep that option, but still want to reference the policy as `'GetThings' => [...]` rather than `'StdClass' => [...]`

Comment: What does `doStuff` returns?

Comment: Makes a database (\PDO) call then returns the array, see: https://pastebin.com/raw/0jeNmaB6

Comment: See bottom of post for new update on cause. No solution for it as of yet.

Comment: you can use \PDO::FETCH_CLASS

Comment: @DarkBee What would I set the class as? My PDO connection is in a wrapper so any changes are used site wide.

Comment: Cant u write an extra method which uses FETCH_CLASS?

Comment: So i tried FETCH_CLASS in my main method, and now the template renders fine even without "allowing" the properties in the sandbox? There's nothing allowed, but it renders fine?

Comment: FETCH_CLASS also seems to return duplicate values. I.e. both associated name and index. ` [id] => 2 [0] => 2 [data] => Abc [1] => Abc`, I only want one result set.

Answer (score 0):

It works as intended:

```
{% for i in info %}
    {{ i.id }}       <- Code that raises securityPolicy exception.
    {{ i.data }}     <- Code that raises securityPolicy exception.
{% endfor %}
```

Here `i` is not a `GetThings` instance. It's whatever you instantiated as value for the `id` and `data` key:

```
return array(
    'id'   => '...',
    'data' => '...'
);
```

Twig `for` tag will iterate over the `info` variable, which happens to be a keyed array. So the loop will iterate over the values of the array - in your case '...' and '...' which I guess are stdClass instances.

Comment: The getStuff() method makes a PDO call which returns a standard array. Oh so it happens when it converts the GetThings instance to a loop and iterates over the returned PDO objects. Hm.

Comment: That seems like odd behavior to me, it essentially means I have to put everything in the StdClass, rather than GetThings allowed properties? Is there any way that I could achieve this the way I'm trying to? i.e. GetThings => [...]

Comment: I figured out why it's returning StdClass rather than a GetThings array. Please see bottom of main post for update ^